# adding force with new input system

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the new input system to make a multiplayer game kind of like super smash bros, but I can't seem to get the input system vector2 to work to get the player to move left and right.

this game is in 3d and I'm using the unity engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    //refrence to are action map I think
    public PlayerInput PlayerInput;
    //jump actions
    private InputAction JumpAction;
    private InputAction MoveAction;
    //player stuff
    public GameObject player;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float speed, downForce, jumpPower;
    //analog
    Vector2 analogValue;


    private void Awake()
    {
        //Enable
        PlayerInput.Enable();
        MoveAction.Enable();
        JumpAction.Enable();
        //I dont know what that is
        PlayerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
        //Jump
        JumpAction = PlayerInput.Player.Jump;
        JumpAction.ReadValue<float>();
        JumpAction.started += ctx => Jump(ctx);
        //move
        MoveAction = PlayerInput.Player.Move;
        MoveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        MoveAction.performed += ctx => Move(ctx);
        MoveAction.performed += ctx => analogValue = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(analogValue);
    }

    //move function
    void Move(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
    {
        rb.AddForce(analogValue.x, 0, 0 * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }    

    //Jump Function
     void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
     {
        rb.AddForce(0, jumpPower, 0);
     }
}
```

I'm trying to add more words to this cuz stack overflow wont let do anything if I don't so maybe this is enough

Comment: try using `MoveAction.Enable();` or `PlayerInput.Player.Enable();`

Comment: didn't work I added ```MoveAction.Enable();``` still doesnt work

Comment: I think I'm just gonna make it individual buttons

Comment: never mind that's a lot to deal with

Comment: i think i found the problem, I wasnt calling the function in invoke envets

Comment: i c a n t call the function